# Has there been any satellites that used an 'upside-down' Molniya orbit?

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit

Have there been any satellites that used an orbit similar to what Russia uses, but for the southern hemisphere? Specifically to service South America and Australia/Oceania?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a need.  Cape Horn is only about 55 degrees south, and Australia and New Zealand don't really go more than about 45 degrees south.  Both of those would have clear visibility to a GEO satellite.

Comment: @Tristan see also [Can they watch TV at the South Pole? What satellites are used for data, comms, and entertainment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25325/12102)

Answer (score 4):

One of the NASA TDRS satellites comes within range of the Antarctic SPTR2 ground station
TDRS is not in a Molniya orbit

[SPTR2 ground station](https://www.usap.gov/technology/contentHandler.cfm?id=1971)

[SPTR2 image](https://www.usap.gov/global/popup.cfm?/technology/images/sat-photos-8-lg.jpg&pageTitle=Aerial%20Picture%20of%20the%20SPMGT/SPTR/RF%20Building%20Complex)

Comment: Did you mean to leave this as an answer to [Can they watch TV at the South Pole? What satellites are used for data, comms, and entertainment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25325/12102) It doesn't seem to really answer this question, but it *certainly does* help to answer that one.

Comment: I think the answer is no. The Soviet Union/Russia never did put into orbit "an upside-down" Molniya. Interesting though the Russians do have Antartic bases :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the follow-up!