# Can they watch TV at the South Pole? What satellites are used for data, comms, and entertainment?

Tags: communication-satellite, commercial

**edit:** This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26045/12102) adds one more piece to the puzzle, at least for data.

---

For navigation, I believe GPS covers the poles.

For data, there is at least Iridium (see answers to [What (actually) makes Iridium “the world's only truly global mobile satellite communications company”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18823/12102) but there may be government satellites for government sponsored bases as well, but I'm not sure.

And after reading @Tristan's comment below [Has there been any satellites that used an 'upside-down' Molniya orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25321/12102) I realized that the GEO band is way below the horizon for the poles.

So I'd like to know what satellites are used by bases on Antarctica for scientific data up/down link, internet for science and personal use, and for watching TV, especially those near or at the South Pole?

---

For example, I found this image of a GEO satellite receiving dish in this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/alaska/comments/i4pul/alaskan_satellite_dishes_pointed_at_the_ground/), taken "outside Anchorage" and so only at about 61 degrees North latitude (cropped, click for full size) This kind of antenna (often) uses an offset parabola, so the incident angle is somewhat higher that you might guess by looking at it. The majority of antarctica is beyond 60 degrees South though. Note that those elevation angles are *maximum values* for a GEO position equal to your longitude. As one gets closer to the poles, the window to useful GEO positions closes quite rapidly.

Table and diagram from [NOAA](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/CORS/Articles/SolerEisemannJSE.pdf):

```
latitude  max elevation (Ellipsoidal model of Earth, degrees)
   60           22.0
   65           16.7
   70           11.5
   75            6.4
   80            1.4
```

[image: Satellite dish near Anchorage cropped] [image: GEO Look angles]

Comment: Start with https://www.usap.gov/technology/contentHandler.cfm?id=1982.  There is a list of satellites and times they are available.  -MBM

Comment: @MBM Are some of those used to watch TV, or for personal internet access during the long winters? They look like "official, government" satellites.

Comment: GPS does cover the South Pole, [see](http://confluence.org/region.php?id=1323). But for best satellite geometry, there should be one vertically above the pole, but there are no GPS satellites on a polar orbit. The precision of the position is somewhat reduced.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_in_Antarctica

Comment: @jwdonahue there really isn't a complete answer there either, but it is very helpful, thanks! I hadn't realized that Orbcomm had polar orbits, that's interesting!

Comment: Can someone elaborate why a question about access to commercial satellites for personal and entertainment use, at the south pole where the GEO constellation is invisible, is off-topic here? Much of the entire space industry was funded by people watching TV. We have dozens of questions about communications satellites in GEO orbits. Now I'm asking about geographic location on the Earth where that orbit is inaccessible, and alternative orbits need to be used. Are questions about the commercial and civilian uses of space going to be off-topic from now on?

Comment: uhoh, satellites are used for operational and scientific data first, but the bandwidth is available for personal use after that.  So, skype is possible, but I do not know about other phone connections.  McMurdo does have phones, and TV.  I think ATS-3 finally died, but it could support a phone call.  -MBM

Comment: @MBM Thanks! Consider posting an answer to that effect? That they *do not currently have access to commercial satellites*, and must "borrow" bandwidth from government satellites? I think that's a relevant point.

Comment: This article could be incorporated into a good answer if someone is so inclined: https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/194696-an-antarctic-adventure-the-life-of-a-south-pole-communications-technician

Comment: @KeithThompson excellent article, thank you! **update:** I've just added a bounty to this question.

Comment: uhoh, I just consulted with a friend who has spent years at Pole, and who responds that the website above is a good source.  I have not been on the ice for more than a decade, but at Palmer we used ATS-3 for intermittent internet and phone coms,  In the early 2000s in McMurdo we had phones and military TV channels in the dorm rooms.  The US program in Antarctic is a government operation so would use federal satellites first.  In the field we used Inmarsat, Irridium and other commercial channels.

Comment: @MBM fwiw here's a circa 2016 video of McMurdo where the narrator "Kate Miller on the IceCube Neutrino Observatory 2016 Expedition" says "You’ll notice that there are TV monitors almost everywhere. Those are projecting important information like when the satellite is up to get internet…" https://youtu.be/vrPiVT23MhA?t=622 Obviously not much help but I just ran across it by accident (YouTube suggestions while procrastinating)

Comment: @MBM actually there's a link here near the top that goes to a schedule and several more at the bottom. If you can understand it better than I can, you may be able to write an answer here. https://www.usap.gov/technology/contentHandler.cfm?id=1935